# Free TCL IDE for Solaris

Tags: ide, tcl, solaris, activetcl

I have been using ActiveTCL on my windows desktop, but now I have a Solaris workstation, and I need a new IDE. I am a student, so the business edition of ActiveTCL is not an option. Are there any free TCL solutions for Solaris?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you will be able to do for free is vim with syntax highlighting. You can use frink to help look for errors. 
If you still have access to a windows machine you can use notepad++ with the ssh module. That seems to work pretty well and is relatively seamless.

Comment: You can also find compatible IDE on http://wiki.tcl.tk/1184 but I agree with user1797619 that vim or emacs are good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Both vim and emacs are good choices, and Eclipse has a dynamic programming add on that supports Tcl too. Personally, while I use Eclipse for things like Java, I find a simple editor (with syntax highlighting) like emacs much more convenient.